# Prevent frame dropping while saving frames to disk

Tags: c++, multithreading, video-streaming, message-queue

I am trying to write C++ code which saves incoming video frames to disk. **Asynchronously** arriving frames are pushed onto queue by a producer thread. The frames are popped off the queue by a consumer thread. Mutual exclusion of producer and consumer is done using a mutex. However, I still notice frames being dropped. The dropped frames (likely) correspond to instances when producer tries to push the current frame onto queue but cannot do so since consumer holds the lock. Any suggestions ? I essentially do not want the producer to wait. A waiting consumer is okay for me.

EDIT-0 : Alternate idea which does not involve locking. Will this work ?

1. Producer initially enqueues `n` seconds worth of video. `n` can be some small multiple of frame-rate.
2. As long as queue contains `>= n` seconds worth of video, consumer dequeues on a frame by frame basis and saves to disk.
3. When the video is done, the queue is flushed to disk.

EDIT-1: The frames arrive at ~ 15 fps.

EDIT-2 : Outline of code :

#### Main driver code

```
 // Main function
 void LVD::DumpFrame(const IplImage *frame)
 {

     // Copies frame into internal buffer.
     // buffer object is a wrapper around OpenCV's IplImage
     Initialize(frame);

     // (Producer thread) -- Pushes buffer onto queue 
     // Thread locks queue, pushes buffer onto queue, unlocks queue and dies
     PushBufferOntoQueue();

     // (Consumer thread) -- Pop off queue and save to disk
     // Thread locks queue, pops it, unlocks queue,
     // saves popped buffer to disk and dies                
     DumpQueue();

     ++m_frame_id;
}

void LVD::Initialize(const IplImage *frame)
{

    if(NULL == m_buffer) // first iteration 
         m_buffer = new ImageBuffer(frame);         
    else    
         m_buffer->Copy(frame); 
}
```

#### Producer

```
void LVD::PushBufferOntoQueue()
{   
     m_queingThread = ::CreateThread( NULL, 0, ThreadFuncPushImageBufferOntoQueue, this, 0, &m_dwThreadID);
}

 DWORD WINAPI LVD::ThreadFuncPushImageBufferOntoQueue(void *arg)
 {

     LVD* videoDumper = reinterpret_cast<LVD*>(arg);
     LocalLock ll( &videoDumper->m_que_lock, 60*1000 ); 
     videoDumper->m_frameQue.push(*(videoDumper->m_buffer));
     ll.Unlock();   
     return 0;
 }
```

#### Consumer

```
void LVD::DumpQueue()
{   
    m_dumpingThread = ::CreateThread( NULL, 0, ThreadFuncDumpFrames, this, 0, &m_dwThreadID);       
}

 DWORD WINAPI LVD::ThreadFuncDumpFrames(void *arg)
 {
        LVD* videoDumper = reinterpret_cast<LVD*>(arg);

        LocalLock ll( &videoDumper->m_que_lock, 60*1000 );
        if(videoDumper->m_frameQue.size() > 0 )
        {
           videoDumper->m_save_frame=videoDumper->m_frameQue.front();
           videoDumper->m_frameQue.pop();
        }
        ll.Unlock();    

    stringstream ss;
    ss << videoDumper->m_saveDir.c_str() << "\\";
    ss << videoDumper->m_startTime.c_str() << "\\";     
    ss << setfill('0') << setw(6) << videoDumper->m_frame_id;
    ss << ".png";       
    videoDumper->m_save_frame.SaveImage(ss.str().c_str());

    return 0;
```

}

Note:

(1) I cannot use C++11. Therefore, [Herb Sutter's DDJ article](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/writing-lock-free-code-a-corrected-queue/210604448?pgno=1) is not an option.

(2) I found a [reference](http://www.1024cores.net/home/lock-free-algorithms/queues/unbounded-spsc-queue) to an unbounded single producer-consumer queue. However, the author(s) state that enqueue(adding frames) is probably not wait-free.

(3) I also found [liblfds](http://www.liblfds.org/), a C-library but not sure if it will serve my purpose.

Comment: A [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) can be lock free if it is large enough to never fill. If the writing process can't keep up then you'll always lose some frames no matter what you do.

Comment: even if you use the simple-minded locking implementation, if locking to read out a frame holds the lock for long enough to screw up the enqueue thread, then something is wrong.  what you are probably doing is: lock, dequeue, write to disk, unlock.  instead, what you should be doing is: lock, dequeue, unlock, write to disk.  the lock operation locks the quene, not the frame.  you may need a separate lock for the frame, but that is not the issue here.  btw, if you post some code, we can probably give you more insight.

Comment: @MarkRansom: I am using STL queue which is FIFO. Filling up is not a concern.

Comment: @thang: I lock the queue as you recommend - only while dequeueing.

Comment: How about the following ? Producer initially enqueues n seconds worth of video. As long as queue contains >= n seconds worth of video, consumer dequeues on a frame by frame basis and saves to disk. When the video is done, the queue is flushed to disk. This is a lock-free solution.

Comment: your de-queuing takes so long that it causes a frame drop?  something is seriously wrong there.  hard to tell w/o some code.

Comment: @thang, any thread can get stalled by the OS if it decides to let another thread or process execute instead. The key is to eliminate the lock altogether.

Comment: @thang : The frame drop is not because of time taken to deque. As I mentioned in the question, the video frames arrive asynchronously into a buffer. If the contents of that buffer are not copied before the next frame arrives, they are lost. If, at the moment the producer wishes to copy from this buffer onto queue, the consumer holds the lock, the producer waits. In the meanwhile, the buffer could have been overwritten by next frame.

Comment: @MarkRansom, if getting stalled by the OS is an issue, then the problem can't be solved.  the producer thread can get stalled by the OS, too, even if there is no locking mechanism involved.  removing the lock is definitely a good idea in general, but i suspect that is not the main cause of the problem here.

Comment: @curryage, so ultimately, you're saying the consumer thread locks for too long, delays the producer, which causes the the frame drop.  the consumer locks for too long because it takes too long to dequeue.  is that right?  if yes, then something is wrong or you are operating at very very high frame rate.  at 120fps, you have 8ms total to work with per frame.  copying can't take more than 4ms (say 4ms), then you're left with 4ms for waiting on the producer side.  i.e. you have 4ms to dequeue.  you're saying shuffling a few pointers around takes > 4ms?

Comment: @curryage, if your buffer is only one frame long, that's your problem right there. You need to assume that worst case, the consumer is going to temporarily fall behind but will catch up after some period.

Comment: 4ms?  Copying one pointer/reference thakes four milliseconds?

Comment: Are you copying the entire buffer when adding/removing it from the queue, or just a pointer to the buffer? It's not clear from the code which it does [at least not to me!]

Comment: @MatsPetersson - Copying the entire buffer -- code for this added to the original question. If all I have is a pointer to a buffer which gets filled asynchronously(by another process), wouldn't I need to copy its contents ?

Comment: I think I need to edit my answer, as it's becomming a long comment.

Comment: @curryage - not normally, no.  Push the buffer pointer, new() another buffer instance, (or pop one from a pool), and start filling the new instance.  Pushing a huge chunk of image buffer data onto a wide queue is a bad plan, (CPU wasted on the copy + locks held for too long), and usually avoidable.

Comment: @MartinJames : I like this idea and get what HansPassant was referring to. I also responded to your comment below. Please ignore that.

Comment: You do, of course, have to handle the buffer instances when they are 'finished with' by the consumers.  You can either delete them or push them onto a 'pool queue', (another blocking queue), for re-use by producers.  I usually prefer the pool since it eliminates continual new/delete, prevents memory-runaway, removes the need for complex, bounded queues and provides end-to-end flow control, (if the pool empties, the producers block on it until instances are returned by the consumers, so slowing up the producers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The queue cannot be the problem.  Video frames arrive at 16 msec intervals, at worst.  Your queue only needs to store a pointer to a frame.  Adding/removing one in a thread-safe way can *never* take more than a microsecond.

You'll need to look for another explanation and solution.  Video does forever present a fire-hose problem.  Disk drives are not generally fast enough to keep up with an uncompressed video stream.  So if your consumer cannot keep up with the producer then something is going go give.  With a dropped frame the likely outcome when you (correctly) prevent the queue from growing without bound.

Be sure to consider encoding the video.  Real-time MPEG and AVC encoders are available.  After they compress the stream you should not have a problem keeping up with the disk.

Comment: +1 thank you!  trying to drive at this.  difficult to diagnose w/o any code.

Comment: My design does not involve storing pointers on the queue. Please see edits to my original question where code has been added. For reasons not relevant here, I do not want to encode the video using MPEG etc., but am merely interested in saving frames to disk.

Comment: Well, if you don't want to change the design then there's little point in asking for help.  Copying the entire frame while holding the lock just isn't a very wise thing to do, it is up to you to change it.

Comment: @HansPassant : I am copying the entire buffer -- code for this added to the original question. If all I have is a pointer to a buffer which gets filled asynchronously(by another process), wouldn't I need to copy its contents ? Pushing the pointer to the buffer on the queue won't work.

Comment: @HansPassant is correct - communicating bulk data between threads by copying the entire data is bad.  CPU is avoidably wasted performing the copy and locks are held for long periods, inviting excessive contention.  You should dump this design and queue up pointers/references to buffer instances only so that the producers and consumers never have to operate on the same image instance.

Comment: @MartinJames : I mentioned the reason for copying in comments above and why pushing the pointer to buffer on the queue won't work. Just to point out -- (1) Data arrives into a shared-memory buffer which is filled asynchronously with another process. (2) The problem I am having is not because producer and consumer are acting on same image instance as you mention, but because queue is locked up in some instances when the asynchronously filled buffer needs to be (copied and) pushed onto the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Circular buffer is definitely a good alternative. If you make it use a 2^n size, you can also use this trick to update the pointers:

```
inline int update_index(int x) 
{
   return (x + 1) & (size-1);
}
```

That way, there is no need to use expensive compare (and consequential jumps) or divide (the single most expensive integer operation in any processor - not counting "fill/copy large chunks of memory" type operations).

When dealing with video (or graphics in general) it is essential to do "buffer management". Typically, this is a case of tracking state of the "framebuffer" and avoiding to copy content more than necessary.

The typical approach is to allocate 2 or 3 video-buffers (or frame buffers, or what you call it). A buffer can be owned by either the producer or the consumer. The transfer is ONLY the ownership. So when the video-driver signals that "this buffer is full", the ownership is now with the consumer, that will read the buffer and store it to disk [or whatever]. When the storing is finished, the buffer is given back ("freed") so that the producer can re-use it. Copying the data out of the buffer is expensive [takes time], so you don't want to do that unless it's ABSOLUTELY necessary.

Comment: Considering the task at hand, I think a "circular" buffer of size 3 is plenty.  One to read, one to write, and one just to be safe/easy.

Comment: how can you possibly estimate the size requirement without knowing long term throughput variance of the write operation?

Comment: A ring-buffer of three will work if you can write as quickly as the data comes in (nearly) all the time. However, if it's a shared media where other tasks also read/write to the media, then you may well need (much) more than that. But of course Hans Passant makes a good point above, if the disk isn't capable of sustaining (a bit more than) the data rate from the video-stream, then it's not ever going to work, no matter how long the queue is.

Comment: I wrote 3 on the assumption that writing a frame is _far_ slower than recieving one, and in the time taken for any one to save, one or more will have arrived, which will drop.  Any more than 3 won't help anything, unless the write operation is usually slower than but _occasionally_ faster than the rate at which frames are recieved.

Comment: @MooingDuck, the most common scenario is that writing is faster than receiving, and occasionally it is slower (e.g. when another program writes to disk at the same time).  these "blips" cause you to accumulate frames in the buffer.  dropping frames is a scenario you want to avoid, so what people do is make this buffer large enough to account for the anticipated blips (write throughput variance).  if writing is far slower than receiving, what you should do is plan frame drop (e.g. every other).  you never want random frame drop as this will cause jitter in playback!

Comment: @MatsPetersson - The writes to disk are being handled by a separate thread, which can work at its own sweet pace. Disk latency is not an issue here.

Comment: That's true as long as your overall disk throughput is higher than the output of the camera - say you have a camera producing 60MB/s, and your disk can only take 30MB/s - doesn't matter how long you make the queue, eventually, you will drop frames - longer queue will just make it later. And of course, if the separate thread doesn't get to run often enough/long enough, that's also a potential problem. But yes, it shouldn't be a big problem if you have enough capacity everywhere.

Comment: @MatsPetersson - You make an interesting point about the separate thread not getting to run often enough or long enough. One possibility is to make only the consumer thread sleep for a while before dying. I have also added a lock-free idea as EDIT-0 in my original question above.